# In matrix, set rows to correspond to values in a category

Tags: matrix

I'm thinking of using Matrix to get around EE's limitation in only having one image field for categories.

Is there a way to write a plugin that will automatically populate rows in matrix for each category?

Maybe the plugin could be executed after saving a category if there's a new value update a specific matrix field...

Hmm.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how the categories are supposed to be tied to the Matrix? Are you looking to set an image for each category in each entry? Some context would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a technique I have used in the past that uses channels as categories. Its pretty niffty as you can have any fields you like in the categories section.

• Create a channel called categories (Or whatever)

• Create a channel that you want to categorize (say, products)

• In the 'products' channel, add a Playa or native relationship FT to it that only looks at the 'categories' channel.

You can then use that relationship field display your entries for that cat. You can also create a better URL structure for SEO this way, and go to town on the categories fields.

It can be a bit of a pain getting your head around, but it is really powerful.

The whole native EE cats really need a good going over in my mind as they are quite limiting compared to teh rest of EE. I believe there are some new category hooks in 2.7, so fingers crossed a dev will take up the challenge.

As far as your question goes, I don't think there is anything available at the mo. I'll try and think of another way round, but the above is potentially a good way to go.

Hope it helps

Comment: I ended up still using EE categories but storing all my primary display info for categories in a channel. I use seg2cat to map categories to channel entries using identical url-titles.

Comment: Sweet. Sounds like a nice approach. Glad it all worked out for you.